# Forcing table output by geoprocessing to be added to TOC?

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, python-script-tool, in-memory

In ArcMap I can set a Geoprocessing option to add geoprocessing output to my table of contents (Geoprocessing > Geoprocessing Options...)

[image]

If this option is enabled my script output will be added to the table-of-contents, but if it's not enabled it isn't added.  This happens even if I have output parameters set in my tool and `arcpy.SetParameter()` in my script.

Is there a way I can force an output to be added to my ToC when a tool is run?  The output is a temporary table (`in_memory`) that users need to be able to access once the tool is run in the current ArcMap session.

```
import arcpy

testabc = r"in_memory\testabc"
myTable = "mytable"
in_memory = "in_memory"

output = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(myTable, in_memory, "testabc", "", "", "")

arcpy.SetParameter(0, output)
```

[image]

Comment: My first thought is "no". There is this `arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap`, but I'm pretty sure the application setting (arcmap's environment) trumps the environment in the tool.

Comment: @KHibma oddly when I try that the table actually appears in the ToC for a split second before disappearing again.  Without that `env` variable set it doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Is `AddTableView` and `RefreshTOC` an option?

Comment: @PolyGeo I'll need to read up on `AddTableView` - does this need `MakeTableView` first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@PolyGeo's suggestion of looking at `AddTableView` was the right one:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame

testabc = r"in_memory\testabc"
myTable = "mytable"
in_memory = "in_memory"

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(myTable, in_memory, "testabc", "", "", "")

mytableview = arcpy.mapping.TableView(testabc)
arcpy.mapping.AddTableView(df, mytableview)

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

This successfully adds the `in_memory` table as a table view in the MXD that can be viewed by the user.